# Is it possible to edit the "About" section on settings Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop?

Tags: settings

Is it possible to edit the About section on settings? I want to edit the "Hardware Model Name"

[image: About Section]

Comment: No that is coming from the computer not the OS.

Comment: I want to keep it simple, Acer Nitro then remove the remaining. I did it on Windows, I thought I can do it on GNU Linux OS. If that's the case, I'll leave it as it is.